# Android - on the fly scaling faster than prescaling, wtf?

Tags: android, bitmap, scaling

I am trying to program my first Android game, which contains moving circular objects with a bitmap over them.

I decode the png:

```
moon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.moon);
```

Then, for each Ball object I do this in the beginning (they can be different sized):

```
scaledMoon=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(game.moon, (int)(r*2), (int)(r*2), true);
```

And when drawing on the canvas I do this:

```
c.drawBitmap(scaledMoon,x,y, null);
```

Doing this with 100 objects, I get a nearly constant render time of 22ms.

But when I do it like this (without scaling before!)

```
c.drawBitmap(game.moon, new Rect(0,0,game.moon.getWidth(),game.moon.getHeight()), new Rect((int)(x-r),(int)(y-r),(int)(x+r),(int)(y+r)), null);
```

I get 17ms render time...

When drawing just a circle

```
c.drawCircle(x, y, r, color);
```

I get 24ms

**What the ...?**

Answer (score 1):

your 3rd line that renders the fastest is because your reusing the same bitmap instead of filling video memory with all the bitmaps you tried preloading before; Its not making a new one, its just setting the bounds for what you want to draw. As for 24ms for drawing a circle, my best bet is that it takes longer to calculate and draw the points then a simple rectangle.

Comment: I just tried, I used a global scaled bitmap and rendered it using `c.drawBitmap(scaledMoon,x,y, null);`
It had the same result (22ms)